# Why won't my CSS stylesheet link in Grails?

Tags: html, css, grails, web, groovy

I have this very basic index.gsp file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test">This should be in cursive and blue</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a very basic main.css file:

```
.test {
    font-family: cursive;
    color: blue;
}
```

The path of main.css is web-app/css. I feel like this is a very trivial problem, but I can't get my  line to show up in cursive and blue. However when I add the following to the head segment of my gsp file it works just fine:

```
<style>
.test {
    font-family: cursive;
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Why won't my css file work with my gsp file?

BuildConfig.groovy file for reference:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your application using the resources or asset-pipeline plugin? If so, you're supposed to include resources (e.g. CSS and JavaScript files) in pages by defining modules/bundles of resources, and including those (rather than individual files).

See the docs for the [resources](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/) or [asset-pipeline](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/) plugins for more details.

Comment: Unless those plugins are included by default, then no. Do I need to use these plugins simply to use CSS?

Comment: They are, look in your BuildConfig.groovy to see what plugins you have installed.

Comment: asset-pipeline is included by default since Grails 2.4.X, before that resources was included by default.

Comment: you don't have to use either of these plugins to include CSS, but we need to know if your app is using them in order to answer your question

Comment: It looks like I am using the runtime ":resources:1.1.6" plugin. Is there a way to not use this plugin and use simple CSS? Would I be missing something fundamental if I do that?

Comment: if you remove the plugin you can just include the CSS/JS files individually.

Comment: It works, thank you! From what I understand from the grails resources page you linked, by removing the plug in I will be mainly missing out on performance enhancements when including resources. Is there anything else I should be particularly aware of?

Comment: The main benefits of the resources plugin are performance enhancements, and the convenience of working with bundles of resources rather than individual files. If your app only has a small number of CSS/JS files, and performance is not a problems, then using the resources plugin may be overkill.